# GORM findAll doesn't work

Tags: grails, grails-orm

A have class Product:

```
class Product {
    static hasMany = [attributeValues: ProductAttributeValue]

    String productId
    String manufacturer
    BigDecimal price

    static constraints = {
        productId unique: true, blank: false
        manufacturer blank: false
        price min: BigDecimal.ZERO
    }
}
```

I want to find all products, which productId contains substring 'filter'.
I wrote next code:

```
Product.findAll {it.productId.contains(filter)}
```

But it doesn't work. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should't work at all!
you have 2 options here:

1) you use propper `GORM` techniques like `criteria query` or `HQL`, the would look like:

```
Product.findAllByProductIdIlike( "%${filter}%" ) // dyn-finders
Product.withCriteria{ ilike 'productId', "%${filter}%" } // criteria    
Product.findAll{ ilike 'productId', "%${filter}%" } // criteria
Product.findAll( "from Product where productId like '%?%'", [ filter ] ) // hql`
```

2) or use filtering on the whole dataset in grails app's memory (instead of the db) - NOT recommended:

```
Product.list().findAll{ it.productId.contains(filter) }
```

Comment: Hi injecteer, what about "Ilike" in dynamic finders ? Do you think "Product.findAllByProductIdIlike('%' + filter + '%')" could work ?

Comment: it definitely works. Updated my answer, I let it out, cause I've never used it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex,
Try this :

```
def yourProductIsWithFilter = '123filter456'  
def matchingPattern = 'filter'
//def patternToMatch = /\b${matchingPattern}/\b  
//def patternToMatch = /[A-Z_0-9${matchingPattern}/]
def patternToMatch = ~/.${matchingPattern}/

Product.findAll{it.productId =~ patternToMatch }
```

Note: I haven't tested the code.
Hope it gives you a heads up.
Regards